# Pandas: writing a Pivot Table with all its columns to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx, writer

I want to write a Pivot Table from pandas into a excel sheet but i lose one cell level of information and i coud not find a solution while browsing the web.

Here is what i got in a pivot table made out ouf a DataFrame:

```
T-Class     <00.5   <01.0
ZIP         
0   1375.0  762.0
1   2177.0  913.0
```

when i write it to excel i lose the the cell 'T-Class' with its corresponding empty row for 'ZIP' this is what i get using the xlsx writer:

```
ZIP <00.5   <01.0
0   1375    762
1   2177    913
```

example code for writing to excel:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='pivottable',header = True,index=True)
writer.save()
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: `T-Class` is the name of the `columns` object.  `to_excel` doesn't bother writing out the name of the `columns` object.  If you want this exact format, you'd need do some custom writing.  Totally doable, but not easily achievable via the `to_excel` options.

Comment: Can you maybe give example code or a hint how to do this exact format?

Answer (score -2):

Now that i got back to the export topic of pivot tables for pandas dataframes i found a better library for exports. Openpyxl! With openpyxl its possible to open predefined excel templates write your dataframe data below a predefined nice looking tablehead this way its not necessary to deal with the unneccessary xlsxwriter bugs. Here is example code in openpyxl:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook.active = 0
worksheet = workbook.active
worksheet.title = 'XYZ'
#check length of df
depth_df_2 = len(merged_plz_all)
#call special method to comfortably write the dataframe below your
#predefined header
update_range(workbook.active,merged_plz_all,cell_range =
'A18:'+str(spaltenindex[len(merged_plz_all.columns)])+str(depth_df_2+17))
workbook.save('yourNicelyLookingPivotTable.xlsx')
```

And here is the required update_range method which i found in another stackoverflow thread. I unfortunately didnt bookmark it so i ask for forgiveness for not providing the origin of the update_range method. Personally i find this method should be part of the library openpyxl itself!

```
def update_range(worksheet, data, cell_range=None, named_range=None):
"""
Updates an excel worksheet with the given data.
:param worksheet: an excel worksheet
:param data: data used to update the worksheet cell range (list, tuple, np.ndarray, pd.Dataframe)
:param cell_range: a string representing the cell range, e.g. 'AB12:XX23'
:param named_range: a string representing an excel named range
"""

def clean_data(data):
    if not isinstance(data, (list, tuple, np.ndarray, pd.DataFrame)):
        raise TypeError('Invalid data, data should be an array type iterable.')

    if not len(data):
        raise ValueError('You need to provide data to update the cells')

    if isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
        data = data.values

    elif isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
        data = np.array(data)

    return np.hstack(data)

def clean_cells(worksheet, cell_range, named_range):
    # check that we can access a cell range
    if not any((cell_range, named_range) or all((cell_range, named_range))):
        raise ValueError('`cell_range` or `named_range` should be provided.')

    # get the cell range
    if cell_range:
        try:
            cells = np.hstack(worksheet[cell_range])
        except (CellCoordinatesException, AttributeError):
            raise ValueError('The cell range provided is invalid, cell range must be in the form XX--[:YY--]')

    else:
        try:
            cells = worksheet.get_named_range(named_range)
        except (TypeError):
            raise ValueError('The current worksheet {} does not contain any named range {}.'.format(
                worksheet.title,
                named_range))

    # checking that we have cells to update, and data
    if not len(cells):
        raise ValueError('You need to provide cells to update.')

    return cells

cells = clean_cells(worksheet, cell_range, named_range)
data = clean_data(data)

# check that the data has the same dimension as cells
if len(cells) != data.size:
    raise ValueError('Cells({}) should have the same dimension as the data({}).'.format(len(cells), data.size))

for i, cell in enumerate(cells):
    cell.value = data[i]
```

Comment: while it looks like a good answer, it is an answer to a totally different question. This is not what op asked.